# AngularJS Service returning serialized data?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code.

AngularJS factory

```
.factory('Suggest', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource(baseUrl+'/suggest', {}, {
            query: {
                method:'GET',
                isArray: true
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Controller

```
.controller("SearchFormController", function($scope, $http, Suggest) {
    Suggest.query(
            function(data) {
                $scope.suggestions = data;
            }
        );
    ...
});
```

And the WebService that respond this structure when I hit baseUrl/suggest

```
[
    "0 800",
    "0800 atencion al cliente",
    "19114",
    "19116",
    "2 x 1",
    "30201001992029174",
    "a donde tengo que enviar el mensaje para comprar un paquete de mensajes",
    "a que velocidad navego",
    "abono",
    "abonos",
    "acceder",
    "acceder a mi cuenta",
    "activacion",
    "activacion chip",
    "activacion de chip",
    "activacion de linea",
    "activar",
    "activar chip"
]
```

### The problem

I'm using an [autocomplete library](https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete) who needs the $scope.suggestions as an array.
The problem here is that i'm getting (for some reason that I don't know) a serialized version of the array content, like this

for "a donde tengo que enviar el mensaje para comprar un paquete de mensajes"
i get

```
{"0":"a","1":" ","2":"d","3":"o","4":"n","5":"d","6":"e","7":" ","8":"t","9":"e","10":"n","11":"g","12":"o","13":" ","14":"q","15":"u","16":"e","17":" ","18":"e","19":"n","20":"v","21":"i","22":"a","23":"r","24":" ","25":"e","26":"l","27":" ","28":"m","29":"e","30":"n","31":"s","32":"a","33":"j","34":"e","35":" ","36":"p","37":"a","38":"r","39":"a","40":" ","41":"c","42":"o","43":"m","44":"p","45":"r","46":"a","47":"r","48":" ","49":"u","50":"n","51":" ","52":"p","53":"a","54":"q","55":"u","56":"e","57":"t","58":"e","59":" ","60":"d","61":"e","62":" ","63":"m","64":"e","65":"n","66":"s","67":"a","68":"j","69":"e","70":"s"}
```

**How can I transform this serialized data to string?**

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "for ... i get {"0": ...}." Dumping what gives you the above output you are not expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example for transformation : [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SIRcXjKML5OXVUPWuES4?p=preview).

```
var convert = function (data) {
  var _str = '';
  for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      _str += data[key];
    }
  }
  return _str;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @jackypan1989.. but, is correct to get this serialized data?